# How to fix "No mapping for GET" in a java maven project to show custom error page?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm new to java maven project and I've already spent hours researching and trying things out on how to redirect an http error to a custom error page. But I always get this error

"[http-bio-8080-exec-9] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /errors/error404.html"

I found out that I can use the web.xml to redirect an error page to a custom one and have tried it. Without the "" on the web.xml file, I get the usual error page which is the Apache Tomcat error page. But when I put back the "" on the web.xml file, the error page changes to this outut:

This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

This is supposed to output the html file I created which only have the following message: Sorry, this page does not exist.

But it's not showing and I get the error I've stated above.

Comment: Where is the page located in the project? Spring by default looks for this static page under the location `static/errors/error404.html`.

Comment: It's inside the WEB-INF folder. It was created by the IDE after I typed in the location tag on the web.xml file. I tried to move it on the static folder but it still shows the same error as I've mentioned.